# Asana api to create workspace

Tags: php, asana

I want to create workspace through asana api.In document i think they did not give that facilities to create workspace ? so we can get all the workspace but can we find which workspace is primary workspace? means which they use generally most.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API does not support creating workspaces. There isn't a *guaranteed* order in the workspaces, but generally speaking the first result is a good guess for the primary workspace.